# Android 5.1 load 64 bits shared library failed due to its depend library not found but it indeed exists

Tags: android, load, 64-bit, shared-libraries

I meet an android 5.1 64 bits shared library loading problem.

System:android 5.1.

My apk compresses two xx.so(libA.so & libB.so,libB.so depends on libA.so) into a raw file for limiting apk file size,when launching,the app uncompresses this raw file back to origin libA.so & libB.so to directory /data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a ,now the application calls System.load by passing absolute path:

```
System.load("/data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a/libA.so"); //Success
System.load("/data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a/libB.so"); //Fail
```

As above comments,the first loading of libA.so is success,but the loading of libB.so failed,error info likes :
    dlopen("/data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a/libB.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "libA.so" not found.
But the /data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a/libA.so actually exists,may be not in the right place?

I've tested 32 bits version, this problem doesn't exists.
And I've also tested this on another device Sumsumg Galaxy S6 with system Android5.0,this problem doesn't exists neither.

I've tried copying libA.so to /data/data/MyApp/lib,but got a permission deny error.

Does anyone meet the same problem or any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a 64bit LG G Flex 2 @ Android 5.0. I guess it's a yet another Android OS bug (gdb shows that solist array might get corrupted in the linker), you probably need to **use rpath ELF property as a workaround** (patching it whenever you move your libraries to a new place). I'd recommend you recompiling your libraries with a loooooong rpath to make patching more easy. You can also try to just set rpath to "/data/data/MyApp/files/arm64-v8a/"

Comment: It is still fail after changed rpath.:(

Comment: what is the *use rpath ELF property as a workaround*? Like, is there a link or something?

Comment: @er0 maybe I can write a blog in the future. It's unnormal way.

Comment: @kangear Until you write that blog, mind sharing a few hints about your solution? Did you end up calling dlopen() directly in native code?

Comment: @er0 Maybe it's a OS bug, but I tried to suit this bug. A as 1.SO, A & B as 2.SO, load 1.so, then load 2.so, there are no depends problem, the everything worked fine. load use System.load not dlopen. (sorry about my poor English)

Comment: @kangear Sorry, this (loading in topological order) does not work. In fact, this not working is what the question was about.